# Javascript and more advanced sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I know there's been a lot of questions like these around the site, but I'm in a struggle and I have tried to do my homework before asking.

I have an array of objects that each have three fields. Status, Type, and Time. All are integers.

- **Status** is between 1-9 and represents an availability and everything
  is sorted by status.
- **Type** represents if the user is 0 - "Paid" or 1 -"Free". And paid are
  always above free.

this is my code for that

```
  function sortListings(obj1, obj2) {
        var statusA = obj1.status;
        var statusB = obj2.status;

        var typeA = obj1.type;
        var typeB = obj2.type;

        if (typeA == typeB) {
                return (statusA < statusB) ? -1 : (statusA > statusB) ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
            return (typeA < typeB ) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
```

And this works great. Now sometimes two objects will have the same status and be in the same pay type. So I'd like, in this case, to present the latest time stamp first.

- **Time** is stored as an int ( unix )

I don't know how to go about this. Here is my attempt :

```
  function sortListing(obj1, obj2) {
        var statusA = obj1.status;
        var statusB = obj2.status;

        var typeA = obj1.type;
        var typeB = obj2.type;

        var timeA = obj1.time;
        var timeB = obj2.time;

        if (typeA == typeB) { // has the same type
            if (statusA == statusB) { // has the same status
                return timeA - timeB; //so sort by time
            } else { // different statues, same type
                return (statusA < statusB) ? -1 : (statusA > statusB) ? 1 : 0; // sort by status
            }
        } else {
            return (typeA < typeB ) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
```

As you can see my knowledge of the inner workings of sort is not that great.
Any articles, answers or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: use simple sorts more than once to sort by time, then by type, then by status to sort them with status being most important, type breaking ties, and time breaking remaining ties...

Comment: I think your code is correct. Is it not working correctly?

Comment: @Barmar I think it looks OK too.

Comment: @dandavis that won't work.

Comment: @Pointy: what do you mean by "won't work"? (my test seems to perform as i described)

Comment: @dandavis repeated calls to `.sort()` will re-sort the whole array without respect to original order. If two entries have types that order them one way, but status values that order them the opposite way, they'll end up in the wrong order.

Comment: @pointy: that's what i thought too, but if that's the case, why does this seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/EZzVs/1/ ? will it break on more than 10 items in v8?

Comment: @dandavis you don't have enough data. Make sure that there are rows that are put in different order when *only* one key is compared.

Comment: @Pointy: i'm not sure what you mean by only one key. are you talking about using rows with missing keys? even with only 5 rows, if sort really does "re-sort the whole array without respect to original order",  why does the fiddle work at all? are you generalizing or am i just getting lucky? -tnx

Comment: @dandavis sorry I see; you're going *backwards*; durrr.  Well that will work if the sort is stable, which is something I've looked into in the past but I can't remember what I determined.  (A "stable" sort is one that leaves elements that compare as equal in their original order.)

Comment: ok, then it's an artifact of the "under 11 items" stability in v8... thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would structure the code differently. Compare the most significant key first, then the next most significant, and so on. Only when you've compared all keys and found them all to be equal do you return `0`.

```
function sortListing(obj1, obj2) {
    var statusA = obj1.status;
    var statusB = obj2.status;

    var typeA = obj1.type;
    var typeB = obj2.type;

    var timeA = obj1.time;
    var timeB = obj2.time;

    if (typeA < typeB)
      return -1;
    if (typeA > typeB)
      return 1;
    if (statusA < statusB)
      return -1;
    if (statusA > statusB)
      return 1;
    if (timeA < timeB)
      return -1;
    if (timeA > timeB)
      return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, any time you see a piece of code that looks like the same thing repeated over and over, a light should go off in your head that something can be generalized:

```
function compareKeys(k1, k2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < k1.length; ++i) {
    if (k1[i] < k2[i]) return -1;
    if (k1[i] > k2[i]) return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function sortListing(obj1, obj2) {
  return compareKeys([obj1.type, obj1.status, obj1.time], [obj2.type, obj2.status, obj2.time]);
}
```

Another refinement:

```
function pluck(obj, keynames) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < keynames.length; ++i) // could be done with .map()
    keys.push(obj[keynames[i]]); 
  return keys;
}

function sortListing(obj1, obj2) {
  var keynames = ["type", "status", "time"];
  return compareKeys(pluck(obj1, keynames), pluck(obj2, keynames));
}
```

Comment: Using your first example, time still doesn't get sorted when in same status and same type =/. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: @TheodoreEnderby Yes, it should be fine - are you 100% sure that the time values are really different? (Your own code should work too, for that matter, so maybe you should double-check that the time values are what you think they are.)

Comment: I'm using livestamp to get values like one hour ago thirty minutes ago, I'm going to disable that and make sure because @Alnitak solution does not work either

Comment: @TheodoreEnderby you could always drop in a `console.log()` call to see what the time values look like.

Comment: @Pointy notwithstanding there's some question over how the timestamps work, this generalised solution doesn't readily handle the case where a field is to be sorted in reverse order.

Comment: http://weskamouse.net/sort.png is the result, and I've checked those same unix values are going into the sort function

Comment: @TheodoreEnderby so what happens with my answer?  p.s. in your question I find it somewhat unclear which order the fields are actually supposed to be sorted by.

Comment: @Alnitak well that'd take a different way of building the two lists of key values; if you swap the keys it'd be possible. I wasn't intending to build a new framework here :)  Just an example.

Comment: @TheodoreEnderby I would still add debugging code to the comparison so that you can see exactly how it's behaving.

Comment: @Alnitak your answer is the same I'm begining to think that the values are going in as strings

Comment: Sorting only by time is not working either, @pointy I'm not sure how to use console.log() in regards to the sort function can you elaborate on that for me?

Comment: @TheodoreEnderby well the idea is to see what the values are. You could also use the browser debugger and set a breakpoint there (that might be easier in fact; just set a breakpoint where the first time-based comparison is, and you'll be able to inspect the values).

Comment: I just dumped console stylee and you're right, the time values are all the same!

Comment: It is now up and running as expected thanks a lot for your help  @Pointy

Comment: @Pointy BTW, your first (non-generalised method) would IMHO be better written as `if (typeA != typeB) return typeA - typeB; ...` - only one test for each key.

Comment: @Alnitak yes but that would only work for numeric keys. (I guess that's what you mean by "non-generalized".)

Answer (score 5):

Your main issue is fall-through to less significant fields if the higher level fields are identical.  Try this:

```
function sortListing(obj1, obj2) {

    function compareType(a, b) {
        return a.type - b.type;
    }

    function compareStatus(a, b) {
        return a.status - b.status;
    }

    function compareTime(a, b) {
        return a.time - b.time;
    }

    return compareType(obj1, obj2) ||
           compareStatus(obj1, obj2) ||
          -compareTime(obj1, obj2);      // negative to reverse order
}
```

The `||` short circuit operator will cause the second (and subsequently third) comparison to be evaluated only if the prior comparison returns 0.  The sort order is trivially changed just by changing the order in which the three functions are called.

The inner functions could, of course, be exposed in a higher level scope, allowing you to use each of those comparator functions individually, or in alternate orders.

Note also how this method avoids dereferencing any of the object properties unless absolutely necessary.  If you were sorting thousands of entries that can make a significant difference, although in practise that might be offset by the potential expense of making three function calls internally....  Only benchmarks can really tell.

Comment: I like the simple, recursive structure of this.

Comment: @Barmar well, it's not actually recursive, but the `||` operator makes it far easier to reason about the intent of the function than a whole bunch of nested `if` statements :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't resist trying out a solution that emphasizes the recursive nature of this problem. You're basically comparing two arrays like this: you compare the first elements and if the first elements are the same then you compare the rest in the same way.

Here is the function to compare the arrays (it's assuming that arrays are the same length):

```
function compareArray(a1,a2) {
    if (a1[0]==a2[0]) {
        if (a1.length==1) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
             return compareArray(a1.slice(1),a2.slice(1));
        }
    }
    else {
        return (a1[0]<a2[0] ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Same function with try/catch to check length:

```
function compareArray(a1, a2) {
    var l = a1.length;
    try {
        if (l != a2.length) throw "arrays have diff. size";
        if (l == 0) throw "empty array";
        var h1 = a1[0];
        var h2 = a2[0];
        if (h1 == h2) {
            if (l == 1) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return compareArray(a1.slice(1), a2.slice(1));
            }
        } else {
            return (h1 < h2) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // handle err
    }
}
```

Then you can compare the fields

```
function sortListings(obj1, obj2) {
        var statusA = obj1.status;
        var statusB = obj2.status;
        var typeA = obj1.type;
        var typeB = obj2.type;
        var timeA = obj1.time;
        var timeB = obj2.time;
        return compareArray([statusA,typeA,timeA],[statusB,typeB,timeB])
}
```

Btw you can use the `compareArray` to compare any number of fields.

Comment: FWIW, I find your function names confusing - your `sortArray` function would be better named `compareArray`.  Also, that function will be incredibly inefficient since it potentially takes a new slice of both the arrays being compared at each step.  IMHO this step is _not_ naturally recursive (unless being written in a functional language) and iteration would win out both in terms of ease of implementation and performance every time (c.f. the `compareKeys` function in Pointy's answer)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to change the name of the function.